# REST pass multiple inputs to GET method

Tags: rest

I have deployed a simple REST based application in RAD.

A simple URL is accessed using `http://localhost/<contextroot>/users/<username>` where `<username>` is accessed using `reqeust.getAttributes()`. Now, how do i pass more than one attribute to the REST service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you'll use query parameters:

```
http://localhost/<contextroot>/users/<username>?a=10&b=hello
```

You haven't indicated which language or framework you are using so I can't tell you how to do this in code.

Comment: Also, you can use the URI path, depending on what the parameters *mean*.  If you need more than just query parameters, it should probably have been a POST request.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I use Java / J2EE with RAD / Restlet framework. 
The purpose is to do a Search operation. Allow a "like" Search to be done. There is a need to pass "%" with query parameters.

Comment: @Subramanian: "There is a need to pass "%" with query parameters".  So?  You encode query parameters to escape special characters like that.  Search for "Encoding Query Parameters" for examples.

Comment: As much as I like query parameters, most REST implementations don't use them.

Comment: @ScottDavidTesler: I agree; query parameters are problematic for REST semantics. But I don't see any way around it in this case. The "clean" solution would be to access each attribute individually — `…/<username>/a` and `…/<username>/b`, but that's a nightmare for throughput, latency and backend load. HTTP keep-alives might alleviate the first two, but, without some clever delay-batching, the frontend is still lumbered with issuing multiple separate transactions to the backend. REST is a great paradigm, but it's not a panacea, I'm afraid. Sometimes, it just gets in the way.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use URLs of the style `http://localhost/<contextroot>/comments/<username>/after/<date>`, but that tends to get messy if you wish to include a large number of options.